# How to stop Google Chrome modifying URL

Tags: google-chrome

I'm writing a web application.

I want to access

`http://localhost:8080/account?id=16`

Google Chrome constantly modifies this url and sends requests to

`http://localhost:8080/account/`

Really annoying, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome doesn't actually do this.

You likely have something wrong in the routing of your application, causing the browser to be redirected.  You can prove this with a tool like Fiddler, or even Chrome's developer tools.  Furthermore, if you used a 301 status code when redirecting a client, clients can and will cache this indefinitely.